# Rewrite all request targets in istio ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, istio

In the process of testing out [Istio](https://istio.io/) I'm in need of rewriting all incomming requests on the Istio ingress controller in the same manner as with Kubernetes's own ingress controller, where I use the [`rewrite-target` annotation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/controllers/nginx/configuration.md#rewrite).

```
# Existing Kubernetes ingress configuration
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:    
  rules:
  - host: some.host.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /svc
        backend:
          serviceName: svc
          servicePort: 80
```

This makes all requests, e.g. `http://some.host.com/svc/endpoint` hit the service with `/endpoint` instead of `/svc/endpoint`

How can I effectively do the same with Istio's ingress controller?

The [Route rules](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/traffic-rules/routing-rules.html#httprewrite) object can handle rewrites, but is only available as a per destination manner, i.e. I have to create a route rule for every service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. You need a route rule per service to do setup the rewrite targets. See https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/traffic-rules/routing-rules.html#httprewrite for an example.